# Cannot load Neuroph Library - Class Not Found

Tags: java, neural-network, jar, neuroph

```
import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork;
import org.neuroph.nnet.Perceptron;
//import org.neuroph.core.learning.DataSet;
//import org.neuroph.core.learning.DataSetRow;


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        NeuralNetwork myNeuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.load("mySamplePerceptron.nnet");
        //DataSet trainingSet = new DataSet(9, 1);
    
        //trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }, new double[]{4}));
        System.out.println("Hello.");
    }
}
```

No matter how I try to compile and run this basic file (sometimes with various other additions, such as creating a basic DataSet object) I always get some error stating that the class cannot be found.  Sometimes this error happens when I try to compile the file, stating that the packages or classes do not exist, and other times it does try to run but simply does not find one of the classes, usually either DataSet or NeuralNetwork.  The farthest I have gotten is with all of the above lines of code uncommented is the line with `trainingset.addRow(...)`, which has a "cannot access DataSet" error, and I don't remember how I even compiled and ran the file to get that far.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Compiling the code and running it with all relevant .jar files attached
- Using Netbeans and adding all the .jar files manually
- Using Netbeans and Maven to try to add the neuroph library (when I tried this, Maven simply said it couldn't find anything with the artifactID, even though I used the exact one they had in the documentation)
- Trying to create a Java application in Neuroph Studio (the studio didn't have the option to make a Java application, and was missing a lot of help files.  Note that I DO have JDK 1.8 installed, as well as 1.9)
- Trying the same thing on Linux
- Trying older versions of the library and the studio (the older versions of the framework give the same results, the older versions of the studio just straight up don't work)

Pages that have tried to solve this problem have generally recommended either editing Maven/Netbeans settings or adding all the relevant .jar files.

Has this library been deactivated and abandoned?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but for the sake of whoever will need an answer of the same problem, this is how I did it.

I am using `Neuroph version 2.98` and to load the data just make sure that the `xxx.nnet` file is in same folder with the `src` folder and load it as follow.

```
NeuralNetwork myNeuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork.createFromFile("mySamplePerceptron.nnet");
// ...
//trainingSet.add(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }, new double[]{4})); // Use add() instead of addRow()
System.out.println("Hello.");
```

Refer to their [Getting Started With Neuroph.pdf](https://neuroph.sourceforge.net/Getting%20Started%20with%20Neuroph%202.7.pdf) for more details. Although it is out dated.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately the window I needed this answer has passed, but I worked around it.  I'll leave the question up.